# Safely pass bool value as reference in ObjectiveC

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
@interface MyObj ()
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL cancel;
@end


@implementation

- (void)doSth {
    [AClassObj startDoSthUntilCancel:&_cancel];
}

@end
```

How can I avoid crash (or get incorrect value) after MyObj instance dealloc? As  AClassObj may still visit *cancel in -startDoSthUntilCancel: method.

Or is there any better way to do this cancel action?

Comment: `[AClassObj startDoSthUntilCancel:self];`?

Comment: similar to my solution, I don't want AClassObj has to much business with MyObj at first，I used a protocol at last，pass self as a (__weak id<CancelProtocol>)  prameter. thanks :) @Cy-4AH

Comment: It's not clear to me the reason why you are trying to pass the reference of that boolean instead of its value (a value that will keep on living even after the dealloc of MyObj, unlike cancel's reference). Moreover, I don't get how passing "self" would solve your problem, because when you deallocate MyObject, that "self" becomes nil